# How to show that if two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ are tangent to a submanifold then so is their Lie bracket?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $Q$ be a submanifold of $M$. Consider two vector fields $X, Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that $X_q, Y_q\in T_qQ$ for every $q\in Q$. Prove that $[X, Y]_q\in T_qQ$ for every $q\in Q$.

So, I came across the following proposition in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifold":

> **Proposition 8.22.** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $S\subseteq M$ be an embedded manifold with or without boundary, and $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. Then $X$ is tangent to $S$ if and only if $(Xf)|_S=0$ for every $f\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $f|_S\equiv0$.

Thus, I thought that I have to show that, for $f\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $f|_Q=0$, we have $[X, Y]_q(f)=0$. But $[X, Y]_q(f)=X_q(Y(f))-Y_q(X(f))=0$ because $Y(f)$ and $X(f)$ are smooth functions on $M$ that vanish on $Q$ and $X_q$ and $Y_q$ are in $T_qQ$. So, I thought that I was done, but my instructor said that this doesn't prove that $[X, Y]_q\in T_qQ$. I don't really understand why, could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: You need to explain more about why you think this proves what you want.

Comment: @Deane Well, to me it seems like I applied the proposition in Lee's book, but I am not sure whether this is really the case or not.

Comment: Yes, I see. Your proof looks good to me.

Comment: @Deane thank you for your input!